# node.js mock sendmailer transporter inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking, aws-lambda

Im working with an node handler in AWS lambda and i need to make another files with integration tests from that function, but i cant mock the transporter with sinon or mockery.

the index.js function:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>
{
  var transporter=createTransporter();
    transporter.sendMail(data, function (error, success) {
        console.log(error);
        response = getResponse(404, error);
    }
    callback(null, response);
    });
}

function createTransporter() {
return nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "SMTP",
    auth: {
        user: "XXXX@XXX",
        pass: "XXXX"
    }
});
}
```

the purpose is to mock the function createTransporter() so that it doesnt send any email when it is called in javascript file test with mocha and expect:

```
var mockery = require('mockery');
var nodemailerMock = require('nodemailer-mock');
var index = require("../index.js");

describe("The handler function tests", function () {
    before(function () {
        mockery.enable({
            warnOnUnregistered: false
        });
        mockery.registerMock('nodemailer', nodemailerMock);
    });

  it('JSON error html ', function () {
        var callback = function (name, response) {
            expect(JSON.stringify(response.statusCode)).to.be('404');
        };
        var context = {};
        index.handler(event, context, callback);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/doublesharp/nodemailer-mock ?

Comment: i did but maybe im doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote `nodemailer-mock` :)

The problem you're having is that you are calling `var index = require("../index.js");` before you are mocking `nodemailer` via `mockery`, so it is already in the module cache. I included `// Make sure anything that uses nodemailer is loaded here, after it is mocked...` in the examples in the README, but should probably make it more clear.

Move the `require("../index.js")` after `nodemailer` is mocked and it will be work as expected.

```
var mockery = require('mockery');
var nodemailerMock = require('nodemailer-mock');

// don't require here since you will get the real nodemailer and cache it
var index;

describe("The handler function tests", function () {
    before(function () {
        mockery.enable({
            warnOnUnregistered: false
        });
        mockery.registerMock('nodemailer', nodemailerMock);

        // do the require() here after nodemailer is mocked
        index = require("../index.js");
    });

    // your tests here should now use nodemailer-mock
    it('JSON error html ', function () {
        var callback = function (name, response) {
            expect(JSON.stringify(response.statusCode)).to.be('404');
        };
        var context = {};
        index.handler(event, context, callback);
    });
});
```

Another option is to use the `{ useCleanCache: true }` option with calls to `mockery.resetCache();`, though I have had mixed results. See [Controlling the Module Cache](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery#controlling-the-module-cache) in the mockery documentation.

Comment: btw - this is going to be true for any module that you mock, at least with `mockery`. If you `require()` a module before mocking it you will cache the real module and not the mocked one.

Comment: does nodemailer-mock work with ES6 imports instead of commonjs require?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why this would fail, but I suggest one of two things:

1. Try doing `var createTransporter = function()`... there's a slight difference here that might be your issue
2. exporting `createTransporter` so you can assign a new value to it, either a mock or not. This isn't very "keep implementation details private", it does work
3. Have your module return a *class*, or object anyway, where you can set some "use this transporter method" value. (ie dependency injection)

Comment: The problem is actually with `mockery` - because `index.js` is required before `nodemailer` is mocked with `nodemailer-mock` it will have the actual module in the cache rather than the mocked one. You have to do the require()/assignment *after* the module is mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following option from Jest:

```js
jest.mock('nodemailer').setMock(/* function mock for module */)
```

Remember to use this at the top of the file, before import or require statements.
Here is the official Jest documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules.